# How to autochange the size of listview in c#

Tags: c#, listview

Can someone tell me how can i set my ListView size to change according to the window size.
So if the user changes the window size, the listView size will changed also.

Thank`s.

Comment: Is this WinForms?  If so, you can use the `Control.Anchor` property to anchor the ListView to all four sides of the window.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: If you're using the Designer in Visual Studio, you can just select your `ListView` and find the `Anchor` property in the Properties pane.  Click it and it'll show you your options.

Comment: Indicate (tag) your platform or GUI library. In .NET there are many ListView classes.

Answer (score 0):

If it is inside of a Container, like a Grid or StackPanel you should be able to set it's Horizontal and VerticalAlignment to "Stretch".